# How to embed combine images together

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Is it possible with some transformation unction like Fourier etc to combine more than one image file(3D) into one file say like a digital album. This combining of files should be a reversible operation such that the individual images can be separated.

I attempted this however I am sure its nothing close to what it should be:

```
img1=imread('lena_gray.jpg');
img2=imread('pic1.jpg');
img3=imread('pic2.jpg');

defimage=pow2(get(0,'DefaultImageCData'),47);
mag=200;
imshow(bitslice(defimage,47,51),'initialmag',mag);
r=bitslice(img1,50,50);
g=bitslice(img2,50,60);
b=bitslice(img3,100,100);
imshow(cat(3,r,g,b),'initialmag',mag);
```

This obviously results an error!

Also, how to achieve the reverse operation? Will cramer's rule of inverse help in demultiplexing the combined images? If so, how to operate Cramer's rule on RGB images?

Comment: You need to be more specific about **what** you are trying to achive and **why**.  Are you trying to blend images together?  Or are you trying to embed a latent image into a carrier image for a steganography-like application?

Comment: @misha : It is a precursor for steganography application but in its nacent form.

Comment: @SKM :  are you trying lossy or lossless approaches?

Comment: @misha: it is preferred to be a lossless approach.

Comment: @SKM : is your primary intent to **hide** the latent images, or to merely **combine** a number of images into a single image?  Also, from your code, exactly what error are you encountering?

Comment: @misha: At the first stage I want to learn how to combine them apart from the normal additive operation and then how to further refine so as to hide them. The error is ??? Error using ==> imshow>ParseInputs
Invalid input arguments; see HELP IMSHOW

Error in ==> imshow at 85
[cdata, cdatamapping, clim, map, xdata, ydata, filename, ...

Error in ==> test at 7
imshow(bitslice(defimage,47,51),'initialmag',mag);

Comment: @SKM: are you working with color or grayscale images?  What is the image depth (8 bit, 16 bit, floating point, etc)?  When dealing with images you really need to be specific about this, and the points that I've asked in previous questions.  Knowing such information makes your question easier to answer for other people.

Comment: @misha: I have already mentioned in my Question that these are 3D images, RGB. But what if i have 3 pictures which are to be manipulated, upon which the operation is to be done are 1 gray scale and 2 RGB. They are dimension 512*512. Even if I have all 3 images in RGB, still there is the same error.

Comment: @SKM : your use of the imshow function is incorrect.  You're giving it three parameters -- do you actually understand what they are?  Please read the documentation.  http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imshow.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to achieve multiplexing and demultiplexing. Try Fresnel Transform instead of Fourier

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a mathematical explanation and I think it can be achieved by Fresnel Transform. But again, how does one do it in Matlab and why since the same can be done through bitslice as suggested by Jonas.

Answer (score 1):

If your images are, say 8-bit unsigned integers, you can store multiple images in non-significant bits. See [this blog post by Steve Eddins](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/17/the-story-behind-the-matlab-default-image/) for an example.

Comment: I read the blog post and attempted something and I have modified my question along with the code snippet but it is not even remotely close and gives error. The images are of uint8. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've provided, I can suggest a couple of approaches for you:

- Store each image in a separate color channel.  This is by far the easiest approach.  You can store up to 3 images this way (one for RGB or YUV).  If your file format supports the alpha channel, you can store 4 images.  This assumes you are working with 8 bits per pixel.
- [Interlace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlacing_%28bitmaps%29) your images.  If you do this losslessly, the output image dimensions will increase (multiplied by the number of images you're combining).  If you're doing it in a lossy way, you will lose spatial resolution (e.g. if you do scanline interlacing of two images, then the vertical resolution will be decreased to half of its original value).
- Jonas already suggested hiding data in lower-order bits, so I won't go much more into it other than say that it's a lossy approach
- Look at [random shuffling](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.shuffle) of image pixels to disguise concatenated images.  The link is for Python, but matlab should have something similar.

Basically, your problem is having to deal a trade-off between the following:

- Output image size.  The trivial case is just tiling the images in a grid.  It's perfectly recoverable, completely lossless but also extremely obvious, and hence probably useless.
- Lossy vs lossless.  Lossy approaches will let you achieve smaller output image sizes.
- Visibility vs recoverability.  The more visible embedded data is, the easier it is to recover it (or at least detect that something is there).  Less visible embedded information is typically more fragile to such things as affine transforms and common image processing operations like blurring.  Read about [watermarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_watermarking) for more info.

That should be enough to get you started.

Comment: In your approach,bullet point 1 , i would need to use bitslice. So, how do i go about it since the code provided in the Question is giving an error.